# How to handle redis cache for frequently update data?

Tags: caching, redis

I have an event reservation system where the current API to retrieve the seats availability is very slow (around 8-10 seconds). Therefore, I am thinking to implement some caching like redis but I am really confuse if redis caching is suitable for system that update data very frequently? If I am to delete the cache everytime when there is a reservation completed (I am talking the reservation can be fully booked within seconds), is redis still suitable in this case?

Comment: yes redis is perfectly suitable for this, it's pretty fast

Comment: @r043v hey there, thanks for such prompt response. Correct me if I am wrong, the flow I am having in my mind right now is to check if cache exist at first, if not, it will call the API and cache the response. Whenever a reservation is confirmed, it will delete the cache so the application will call the API and get the latest response.

Comment: or update the cache instead of delete it when reservation is confirmed to have a pretty fast response next time, but yes your flow is good and redis is perfect for this :)

Comment: @r043v Is there anything else I should be aware of when working with redis like what to do if memory full, data accuracy(if data in cache doesnt match with db), cache expiration, data persistance and etc.

Comment: for persistence & expiration redis work pretty fine, for other things it's at your program to handle it